# Observe calloc, malloc, new event

Tags: c++, allocation

Is it possible receive "messages" when OS allocate memory for object, array and ect. like Objective-C?
I just want to create own `NSAutoreleasePool`.
Thnx.

Comment: If you just want memory to be released automatically, use [smart](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) [pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr).

Comment: If you're in C++, you shouldn't really be using `malloc()` et al.  If you do hook into `malloc()` et al, you have to hook into `free()` too, so that if the code using `malloc()` releases its memory using `free()` (that's most code, of course; people using `malloc()` are usually careful to free it), your code does not try to re-release the memory.

Comment: One immediate issue that comes to mind is that the `new` operator only knows the size (ignoring member versions) and not the type of the object. Therefore you wouldn't be able to call the destructor for the objects before freeing the memory.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on an appropriate platform (using GNU libc), you can specify hooks for `malloc` *etc* to modify their behaviour. Look [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Hooks-for-Malloc.html).